# Self-Made BCD Class - Multiplying BCDs Error

Tags: multiplication, addition, bcd

I am making a BCD class as an exercise for school, and am encountering some issues. Below is my BCD class.

My problem is with the multiplyBCDs method.
It works fine with smaller numbers such as 4,329 * 4, however, with larger products, such as the product of 4,329 and 29,385, I receive a NullPointerException error at the first line of my addBCDs method:

```
int[] added = new int[other.numberOfDigits()];
```

I have tried retracing the problem and could not find the issue. Why am I receiving this error and how could I fix it?

```
public class BCD {
    
private int[] digits;

//Constructor: takes in an array of integers as an argument
public BCD(int bcdDigits[]){
    digits = bcdDigits;
}

//Constructor: takes in an integer argument
public BCD(int bcdDigits){
    int b = bcdDigits;
    int count = 0;
    int c = 0;
    
    int length = String.valueOf(bcdDigits).length();
    
    digits = new int[length];
    while(b >= 1){
        c = b % 10;
        b = b / 10;

        digits[count] = c;
        count++;

    }
    
}

//Returns the number of digits in the BCD
public int numberOfDigits(){
    return digits.length;
}



//Returns the nth digit in a BCD
public int nthDigit(int n){
    if(n >= digits.length)
        return 0;
    else
        return digits[n];
}


//Prints digits in reverse order. After every index divisible by three, it outputs a comma.
public void print(){
            
    int count = 1; 
    
    for (int x=1; x<=digits.length; x++){
        if (digits.length<=3){
            System.out.print(digits[digits.length-x]); }
        else {
            if (digits.length % 3==0){
                if (count % 3==0  && count != digits.length)
                    System.out.print(digits[digits.length-x]+"," );
                else
                    System.out.print(digits[digits.length-x]);
            }
            if (digits.length % 3==1){
                if (count % 3==1  && count != digits.length)
                    System.out.print(digits[digits.length-x]+"," );
                else
                    System.out.print(digits[digits.length-x]);
            }
            if (digits.length % 3==2){
                if (count % 3==2  && count != digits.length)
                    System.out.print(digits[digits.length-x]+"," );
                else
                    System.out.print(digits[digits.length-x]);
            }
        }
        count++;
    }
    System.out.println();
}

//Adds one more digit to the BCD 
public void addADigit(int newDigit){
    
    
    int[] tempArray = new int[digits.length + 1];
    
    for(int x = 0; x < tempArray.length - 1 ; x++){
            tempArray[x] = digits[x];
    }
    
    tempArray[digits.length] = newDigit;        
    digits = tempArray;
        
}

//Adds two BCDs together and creates a new BCD
public BCD addBCDs(BCD other){
    
                //converts the BCD other to an array
    int[] added = new int[other.numberOfDigits()];
        for(int x = 0; x < other.numberOfDigits(); x++){
            added[x] = other.nthDigit(x);
        }
    
    
    int greater[];
    int smaller[];
    int diff;
            
                //finding greater addends
    
    if(added.length > digits.length){
        greater = added.clone();
        smaller = new int[greater.length];
        
        for(int x = 0; x < greater.length; x++){
            if(x < digits.length)
                smaller[x] = digits[x];
            else
                smaller[x] = 0;
        }
    }
    else{

        greater = digits.clone();
        smaller = new int[greater.length];

        for(int x = 0; x < greater.length; x++){
            if(x < added.length)
                smaller[x] = added[x];
            else 
                smaller[x] = 0;
        }   
    
    }
            
    int carry = 0;
    
    int[] sum = new int[greater.length + 1];

    for(int x = 0; x < sum.length - 1; x++){
        sum[x] = ((greater[x] + smaller[x]) % 10 + carry);
        carry = (greater[x] + smaller[x]) / 10;
    }
    
    sum[sum.length - 1] = carry;
    
    
    int[] newSum;
    BCD ans;
    
    if(sum[sum.length - 1] == 0){
        newSum = new int[sum.length - 1];
        for(int x = 0; x < sum.length - 1; x++){
            newSum[x] = sum[x];
        }
        
        ans = new BCD(newSum);
    }
    else{
        newSum = sum.clone();
        ans = new BCD(newSum);
    }
    
    return ans;
    
}
    
public BCD multiplyByTen(){
    BCD ans;
    int[] newDigits;
    
    if(digits[0] == 0 && digits.length == 1){
        ans = new BCD(0); 
        return ans;
    }
    else{
        newDigits = new int[digits.length + 1];
        newDigits[0] = 0;
        
        for(int x = 1; x <= digits.length ; x++){
            newDigits[x] = digits[x - 1];   
        }
        
        ans = new BCD(newDigits);
        return ans;
    }   
}

public BCD multiplyBy(int num){
    BCD ans = null;
    
    if(digits.length == 1 && digits[0] == 0){
        ans = new BCD(0);
        return ans;
    }
    
    else if(num == 0){
        ans = new BCD(0);
        return ans;
    }
    
    else if(num == 1){
        ans = new BCD(digits);
        return ans;
    }
    else if(num == 10){
        BCD ans1 = new BCD(digits);
        ans = ans1.multiplyByTen();
        return ans;
    }
    else{
        int carry = 0;
        int remainder = 0;
        int prod = 0;
        int[] answer= new int[(digits.length)];
        int[] newDigits;
        
        for(int x = 0; x < digits.length; x++){
            prod = (num * digits[x]) + carry;
            carry = prod / 10;
            remainder = prod % 10;
            answer[x] = remainder;
                            
            
            if(x == digits.length - 1 && carry != 0){
                ans = new BCD(answer);
                int length = String.valueOf(carry).length();
                newDigits = new int[length + 1];
                
                int b = carry;
                int c = 0;
                
                while(b > 0){
                    c = b % 10;
                    b = b / 10;

                    ans.addADigit(c);   

                }
                
                }   
            }   
        }
    return ans;
    }
    

public BCD multiplyBCDs(BCD other){
    BCD newBCD = new BCD(0);
    int digit = 0;
    BCD dig = new BCD(0);
    do{
        dig = other.multiplyBy(digits[digit]);
        newBCD = newBCD.addBCDs(dig);
        
        other = other.multiplyByTen();
        digit++;
    }while (digit < digits.length);
    
    return newBCD;
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The code doesn't compile, you're missing multiplyBy and multiplyByTen.

Comment: @RobertBain Sorry! forgot to include it--just edited it to include those two, it should work fine now

Comment: The following main method works for me. What am I missing?

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  BCD bcd = new BCD(new int[] { 4329, 29385 });
  bcd.print();
 }

Comment: @RobertBain That just concatenates the two numbers— this is how I have it in my driver:
    BCD bcd = new BCD(4329);
    BCD bcd2 = new BCD(29385);
  
    BCD bcd3 = bcd.multiplyBCDs(bcd2);
    bcd3.print();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the method:

```
public BCD multiplyBy(int num)
```

In the last else statement, the following condition is never met:

```
if (x == digits.length - 1 && carry != 0)
```

and so "ans" is never set and remains null.

Comment: You're very welcome, glad it helped. Out of curiosity, what did you set it to when the condition wasn't met?

Comment: I just made an else statement under that if statement that said `ans = new BCD(answer)` 
It's been working perfectly for all my tests so far

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] added = new int[other.numberOfDigits()];
```

The only way you can get an NPE on that line is if `other` is null.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I can't figure out why other would be null. The only thing I can think of is the    `newBCD = newBCD.addBCDs(dig);`
 line, but newBCD is set to 0 so I think it should work...

Comment: Then you need to re-examine your assumptions, because it certainly is null.